# change package declaration of multiple java files in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, osx-mavericks

I am including a "sub-project" into my project. To do that I simply copy and paste into my project. Say my project is `com.important.stuff` and the sub-project is `com.redo.things.utensil.pencil`. So I move the content of the sub-project so that the package would now be `com.important.stuff.redo.things.utensil.pencil`. But when I open my project in eclipse, it's all red and I know how to fix it one by one. But is there a batch solution?

My eclipse is `Version: Juno Service Release 2`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Import it in its original folder structure (as named in the package declaration of the original files) then when it compiles no complaints rename the package folder and it will rename the folders and change the package declaration in all files. (Good comment that refactor->rename is the canonical way to performs a rename where you want eclipse to search for all occurrences of the name and change it in a batch manner. It's worth spending time figuring out what everything on that menu does and the keyboard shortcut for rename so you can rename any variable when you realise a more descriptive name for it, or class, or method, or constant, ...)

Comment: One way to rename is through the pull-down menu item *Refactor>Rename*.

Comment: before public class whatevertheclassname is do this

    import com.redo.things.utensil.pencil;

Comment: last century i was coding using a dumb editor and met some some very experienced devs socially. they were having a conversation along the lines of "... and the idiots don't use an IDE they use an dumb editor! ha ha ha" i laughed along like I knew what they were saying and next day installed an IDE with absolutely no idea exactly why this was the "pro" thing to do. I sat down to "read the manual" to figure it out. the moment i saw the refactor menu i promptly set about learning the keyboard shortcuts and testing things out.